# Why does my base template never reload?

Tags: templating, cache

I use template inheritance:

In `_layout.html` every other template is loaded with `{% block content %}{% endblock %}`

The problem: `_layout.html` never reloads. I changed the CSS path in the head tag of `_layout.html` but I never *see* the change reflected. Why?

- restarted MAMP (cache is already disabled)
- restarted computer
- emptied every cache I know of
- cache tags aren't used
- used all different browsers
- deleted the storage/runtime folder

The above steps have no effect, and any changes on `_layout.html` don't appear to do anything. Why might this be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you using PHP 5.5?  If so, [opCache](http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.opcache.php) is enabled by default and that’s probably causing your issue.

Answer (score 8):

For those interested:

**Disabling opCache in Mamp:**

Go to: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/conf/php.ini`.

OP Cache is at the bottom of the file.

Comment out the following lines with a semicolon `;`:

```
[OPcache]
;zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/opcache.so"
;  opcache.memory_consumption=128
;  opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
;  opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
;  opcache.revalidate_freq=60
;  opcache.fast_shutdown=1
;  opcache.enable_cli=1
```